# PHP Mail() error 553

Tags: php, email, smtp

I'm using the mail(); function and it's working but sometimes it returns an error 553. I heard it could be because of:

1. You are attempting to send email to a domain that is not recognized by this server
2. You are attempting to relay email through this server, and have not authenticated

(source: http://www.error-553.net/)

Since it is sometimes working I guess the domain is unrecognizable but how do I overcome this error?

EDIT: I think the problem doesn't come from any of this source, first as I said it is sometimes working AND it is also sometimes working with the domain I'm trying to send email to.

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest not ever using the built-in mail() function; rather, use a library called PHPMailer. It allows you to log into an actual email address via your PHP script and send the email - this will help your emails from being blocked by spam filters - it will also help when your server does not allow relaying of emails without proper authentication.

Comment: thank you Drew, I'll try this do you have any idea where I could get a good tutorial to make it simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before sending your mail, check that the domain:

1. Exists
2. Has an MX record that is valid
3. Is not blacklisted

And in addition, that your local mailserver allows you to relay emails to the outside.

Points 1 and 2 are solved in an easy fashion: `getmxrr("domain.name.com",$arrayOfHosts)` will return true if it finds MX records.

Point 3 depends on which blacklist you want to use. I personally like SBL, which just requires a reverse DNS lookup.

Comment: I looked it up online and here's the result from what I expect being the wrong domain


MX 1 ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM
MX 2 ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM
MX 3 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
MX 4 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
MX 5 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM

Comment: I have edited my question, can you please tell me what you think about it.

Comment: If this is the domain causing the SNAFU, your server needs authentication.

Comment: and how I do this? @SébastienRenauld

Comment: Honestly? Use PHPMailer. I've written enough barebones SMTP clients to tell you this.